# QTreeWidgetItem reparenting

Tags: qt, qtreewidgetitem

I'am trying to set new parent to QTreeWidgetItem, here is my code:

```
 1.if( it->parent() )//'it' is QTreeWidgetItem
 2.   {
 3.       QTreeWidgetItem* parent = it->parent();
 4.       parent->takeChild(parent->indexOfChild(it));
 5.   }
 7.   under->addChild( it );//'under' is new parent of 'it'
```

After the fourth line programm fails with `read access violation at 0x0`.

**EDITED**

```
    Q_CHECK_PTR(under);
    Q_CHECK_PTR(it);

    if( it->parent() )
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* parent = it->parent();

        Q_CHECK_PTR(parent);

        Q_ASSERT( parent->child( parent->indexOfChild(it) ) == it );

        parent->removeChild(it);
        //or
        //it = new QTreeWidgetItem( *(parent->takeChild(parent->indexOfChild(it))) );
        //or
        //it = parent->takeChild(parent->indexOfChild(it));
        //or
        //parent->takeChild(parent->indexOfChild(it));
    }
    Q_CHECK_PTR(under);
    Q_CHECK_PTR(it);
    under->addChild( it );
```

Same result.

Comment: A debugger such as GDB will tell you what is null and what failed.

Comment: Nothing is null, that's the problem. it, under and parent works great until taking or removing child from parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *parent = it->parent();
parent->removeChild(it);
under->addChild(it);
```

basically use `removeChild` insted of `takeChild`

**UPDATE**
`removeChild` Removes the given item from the parent and dosen't return anyting. note that the removed item will not be deleted. but `takeChild` returns the child pointer.

Comment: "parent" is a QTreeWidget* (not QTreeWidgetItem*), but this shouldn't be the problem here. If you still have problems with these few lines I suppose the error is somewhere else, not in what you showed.

Comment: How "parent" can be QTreeWidget? According to qt-help QTreeWidgetItem::parent() returns QTreeWidgetItem*. This can be so only if QTreeWidget is inherited from QTreeWidgetItem.

Comment: @A.Akzhigitov You First code works for me perfectly i strongly suspect that the problem is in your initialization.

Comment: Ok, I'll check this out.

Comment: @MesihAkbari Just one more question. Is there any difference between takeChild and removeChild except return statement?

Comment: @MesihAkbari I found out. removeChild calls take child in the implementation. There is no difference.

Comment: @A.Akzhigitov ok, sorry for not seeing your question. hope you can solve your problems.I'll edit my answer